# how to pass stored procedure value into a webform?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql

I am fresher,i was created  a stored procedure for my sql table and i wanted to display those data into a aspx page..

i need the code for..ajax,js,asp.net

Comment: Googled already? didnt find any article ?

Comment: I Tried Several Times I didnt get the exact code

Comment: I wont Submit this type of questions here thank u for ur feedback..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the top of my head like this:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) {
    con.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("ProcedureName", con)) {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        using(SqlReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()){
            if (reader.HasRows) {
                 while(reader.Read()) {
                     ... process SqlReader objects...
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: sorry, missed the "retrieve" info.

Comment: +1 except you can leave off the `reader.HasRows`. If it doesn't have rows, then `reader.Read()` will return false and the `while` loop will exit.

Comment: Agree, I used to use HasRows part of code for logging purposes... kinda sticked to it and never went back :-)